# Bootstrap popover does not work as expected

Tags: html, jquery, web, bootstrap-5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Bootstrap Popover</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" title="Popover on right" data-content="彈出提示框(Popover)的彈出位置在按鈕右方">
            Popover on right
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" title="Popover on top" data-content="彈出提示框(Popover)的彈出位置在按鈕上方">
            Popover on top
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Popover on bottom" data-content="彈出提示框(Popover)的彈出位置在按鈕下方">
            Popover on bottom
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="left" title="Popover on left" data-content="彈出提示框(Popover)的彈出位置在按鈕左方">
            Popover on left
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Data contents could not be shown after clicking the button]

At least now when I clicked on the buttons, the popovers did show up but the `data-content` still could not be shown on the popovers so what is still missing in order to have the whole popover with the content shown?

Comment: Make sure jquery.js script include is *before* bootstrap.js include.  And popper.js should be after bootstrap.js

Comment: Can you show me how should be the ordering of the links and scripts?

Comment: jquery, bootstrap, popper - as explained above

Answer (score 0):

Change data-placement attributes to data-bs-placement.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/
In bootstrap 5 they use data-bs-placement instead of data-placement
and bootstrap 4 they use data-placement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It still does not work after changing the attribute

Comment: show me the screenshot of the change you made.

Comment: Which screenshot?

Comment: the changes you made in your code

Comment: Yes the above code and the picture are the updated version of my scripts. You may check

Comment: change data-content to data-bs-content then it will work fine. I try it in my editor.

Comment: It works successfully now